# How do I change Images in Xcode with the help of Segmented Control

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I am new to swift and I was just wondering

If I have a Segmented control (first, second) and I want to swap an image display (swap between 2 images when I use the Segment control)

```
  @IBAction func didChangeSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl){
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {    
        }
        else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        }
```

After this step I'm kinda clueless on how to progress I searched a bit online and tried to put in `classname.image = UIImage(named: "image name")`

UPDATED

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewControllerStrengthtraining: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var Squat1: UIImageView!
@IBAction func didChangeSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl){
   let imageName =  sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? "22.jpeg" : "UI.jpeg"
   Squat1.image = UIImage(named:imageName)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   
    print("view loaded")
}
```

}

Fatal error :Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Did you check that IBOutlet Squat1 is connected in storyboard ?

Comment: It should be connected!

Comment: At which line do you get the error ?

Answer (score 0):

When beginning development, learn about validating your data and object instances.

For example, you should:

- make sure `Squat1` is not nil
- make sure you can load the named image

Only *then* should you try to set the `.image` property.

Here's an example:

```
class ViewControllerStrengthtraining: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Squat1: UIImageView!
    
    @IBAction func didChangeSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        
        guard Squat1 != nil else {
            fatalError("Squat1 IBOutlet is not connected!!!")
        }
        
        let imageName =  sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? "22.jpeg" : "UI.jpeg"
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: imageName) else {
            fatalError("Could not load image named: \(imageName)!!!")
        }
        
        Squat1.image = img
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print("view loaded")
    }

}
```

If your image view is not properly connected to the `@IBOutlet`, the program will crash *and it will tell you that*.

If you don't have an image resource by the name you want to load, the program will crash *and it will tell you that*.

If you have added "22.jpeg" and "UI.jpeg" to your `Assets`, the most likely cause of your issue is that you shouldn't refer to the extension.

Change:

```
let imageName =  sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? "22.jpeg" : "UI.jpeg"
```

to:

```
let imageName =  sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? "22" : "UI"
```

Comment: Thank you so much it seems the changing 22.jpeg to 22 was the problem. But when i use the slider it changes from 1 image to nothing any idea what this could be?

Comment: *"changes from 1 image to nothing"* ... do you mean "22" shows up, but "UI" does not?